# Change the text of an existing text item without having to create new text items? Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter

So I asked a similar question before but I didn't really get any replies so this is a follow up question on a comment... The code is below and I have no idea how to stop the text from over lapping each other, I tried to delete it before creating a new text but then it just returns an error about coordinates not being correct so I doubt that's the solution. Could someone please help?

```
fuel = 20
# What happens when you click the space bar
def space(evt):
   # Creates text that tells you the velocity and decreases velocity
   global vy, g, dt, fuel
   f=('Times',36,'bold')
   txt=canvas.create_text(w-100,50,
   text=str(fuel),font=f,fill='white')
   if(fuel<0): return
   fuel -= 1
   canvas.delete(txt)
   canvas.create_text(txt, text=str(fuel))
   vy -= 3*g*dt    
# If space key pressed, the function space happens
root.bind('<space>',space)
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your method, you are creating text twice.

After your first call, there is already a text item created by

```
canvas.create_text(txt, text=str(fuel))
```

If `space` method gets called again, you will create an extra one and this will keep going on for each call.

Instead of delete-create text everytime, you can create a single text item in global scope then change its text value using `canvas.itemconfig()` method.

```
txt=canvas.create_text(w-100, 50, text=str(fuel), font=f, fill='white')
def space(evt):
    ...
    ...
    canvas.itemconfig(txt, text=str(fuel))
```